# Detect forward email count in php

Tags: php, email, count, numbers, detection

I need detect forwarded email count. How often an mail is being forwarded from a particular id. finding the number of mail openings.

But don't know how to detect.

Comment: And exactly how are you planing to do so?

Comment: Well, I have planning for Detecting Email Open but it has been done. Now, i just want to detect forward email count in log file...

Comment: OK, can you please share how are you detecting the email opening? The normal way is to include a 1 pixel transparent image in the email body which the `src` of the image points to a `php` script on your site and when the email opens, the script on your site runs and you get notified that the email has been opened. Do you use same mechanism or something else?

Comment: Yes, I using same functionality..

Comment: But you can not do the same for detecting forwarding. actually you can not detect forwarding at all. Best you can do is count number of email open. you can not detect which email account it being used to open that email, also different mail clients may block images. And users may do a clean-up(delete the image) and then forward the email...

Comment: But I detect to below all:
1. Gmail email client
2. iPhone native email client
3. Outlook 2013 or Outlook 2010 email client
4. Chrome web browser

Comment: You only detect the email client, But you can not detect the actual email account which is being used to open the email. Imagine I have a Gmail account. I receive your email, first open it with my Gmail email client on my mobile phone, then on my computer I again receive the email and open it with my MS Outlook, and then I log in to my gmail using google chrome. Although 3 different application have opened the email, but the email has not been forwarded once. How can you detect that?

Comment: And Then imagine I open the email only once in my google chrome and forward it to one of my friends and he uses my computer(Same IP, Same Browser, but different email account) to open the email in his account. How can you detect it?!

Answer (score 0):

It's all done with good ol' image bugs......

- **Which client was used:** Check the user-agent
- **Whether an email was forwarded:** Done by attaching image bugs to divs
  that are loaded only when the message is forwarded.
- **Whether an email was printed:** bug attached to print stylesheet
- **How long it takes to read an email:** A connection that's kept open, as
  pointed out by Forrest (this is also how Facebook tracks(ed?) whether
  or not you are online on chat).
- **Whether an email was deleted:** Check If a message was read for a short
  period of time or not opened. In fact, they group "glanced" and
  "deleted" together.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958926/track-mass-email-campaigns/2982978#2982978)